# Animate siblings one by one with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to create animation function where I click on lets say the last child in a list, 
then I'll need to move all siblings one by one to the left. So it will go like a wave.

Example: 
Click on child nr.4, sibling nr.1 starts to move to the left out of the screen, and with a short delay sibling nr.2 and so on follow after. So it will be like a wave effect.

I have created a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/10kjn00z/2/

```
  $('#menu li').click(function(){ 
    setVar(this);
        $(this).siblings().animate({left: '-'+tWidth+'px'}, function() {
            $(this).animate({top: '-'+onSet+'px'});
        }); 
});
```

This fiddle is just a short snippet off my code, so there might be code thats isnt in use here. But I'll get the idea.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `setTimeout()` function to achieve what you want.

Here's an example of how you can do it:

```
$('#menu li').click(function(){     
    var speed = 100;
    setVar(this);
    var siblings = $(this).siblings();
    $.each( siblings, function(index,value){
        setTimeout(function(){$(value).animate({left: '-'+tWidth+'px'});}, index*speed);
    });

    var current = this;
    setTimeout(function(){$(current).animate({top: '-'+onSet+'px'})}, 400-speed+siblings.length*speed);     
});
```

Check it out on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arhqgny3/1/)

Answer (score 1):

if all the elements to be shifted belong to the same parent:

```
$('menu li').click(function(event) {
     var list = event.currentTarget.parentNode.children;
     var i = list.length;
     var timeout = 100
     while (i--) {
         setTimeout(function() {
             $(list[i]).animate(/*logic here*/);
         }, timeout);
         timeout += 100;
     }
})
```

This will iterate through all the children of the parent in reverse order and apply the animation. You can also tweak this to only call on certain siblings. If you want them to iterate in order, use the standard `for` loop instead of `while`. The value `timeout` corresponds to milliseconds of delay and you can adjust the initial and increment values to adjust the animation timing.

Comment: Hey, thanks for quick answer. Tried you code, but this moves every li element at the same time.

Comment: Just edited to reflect what you want (I think). Let me know if it needs further adjustments.

Comment: I think you're on to something, but this seems to not work. Nothing happends, and have gone thru everyting. And nothing in console or anything

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that behaviour using jQuery.fn.delay, where the delay-time depends on the elements position in the siblings-list.

```
$('#menu li').click(function(){ 
    setVar(this);
    // call .each on siblings, because each will get a different delay
    $(this).siblings().each(function(index, sibl) {
        $(sibl).delay( index * 250 )
               .animate({left: '-'+tWidth+'px'}, function() {
                   $(this).animate({top: '-'+onSet+'px'});
        });
    });
});
```